# Error in compiling a certificate verifier program

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I want to compile [this](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/javacrypto/BCVerifyISig.txt) program in IntelliJ IDE. But it returns the following three errors:

**1.for this line :**

```
CertStore certs = s.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
```

this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol method getCertificatesAndCRLs(String,String)
```

**2.for this line:**

```
Collection certCollection = certs.getCertificates(signer.getSID());
```

this error:

```
error: method getCertificates in class CertStore cannot be applied to given types;
required: CertSelector
found: SignerId
reason: actual argument SignerId cannot be converted to CertSelector by method invocation conversion
```

**3.and for this line:**

```
if (signer.verify(cert.getPublicKey(), "BC")) verified++;
```

this error:

```
error: method verify in class SignerInformation cannot be applied to given types;
required: SignerInformationVerifier
found: PublicKey,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

---

**These are my imports top of my program :**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.*;
```

and I am added `jdk1.7.0_15` libraries + `bcpkix-jdk15on-151.jar` and `bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar` to my project.

Can anybody please help me to handle this issues?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the author of [this program](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/javacrypto/] about the correct libraries. Quote: "The samples above were compiled with j2sdk1.4.1_02 and require the Bouncy Castle base provider and mail provider Release 1.19+ for both compilation and at runtime."

Comment: This sample (which was created 10 years ago) uses an extremely old version of BouncyCastle; I assume the API is different from the latest version. Please consider looking for a more up-to-date sample for the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps. Hope it will help you because it is tested.

**Step 01:** 
Read byte array from file or convert data object to byte array. 
Sample Code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
fis.read(fileContent);
```

**Step 02:** 
create CMSSignedData object from the byte array. 
Sample Code:

```
CMSSignedData data = new CMSSignedData(fileContent);
```

**Step 03:** 
Get CertStore from the CMSSignedData. 
Sample Code:

```
CertStore certs = data.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
```

Be sure to add BouncyCastleProvider in Security at the first:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());'
```

**Step 04:** 
Get Certificate collection using Signer Information. 
Sample Code:

```
SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) i.next();
Collection<? extends Certificate> certCollection = certs.getCertificates(signer.getSID());
```

**Step 05:** 
Verify sign from signer for each certificate. 
Sample Code:

```
if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert)) ) 
{   
     }
```

Please check that, to fulfuill your objective, you have completed above steps.

I am guessing, either you are making CMSSignedData from wrong data input or the dependent libraries are conflicting each other (*most probable cause*). I have used **bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar** and **bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar** to complete all the tasks.